# String concatenation to generate complementary removals

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, combinatorics

This question is a slight alteration of this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144327/generalizing-a-choose-operation).
Given a string, I want to generate a vector of strings
with x removals. For instance:

```
String a = "ABCD";
int x = 2;
//vector<string> residue = generate(a, x);
//vector residue would have the following elements: 
//"AB", "BC", "CD", "AC" "AD", "BD"
```

Having done this, I would like to generate a second 
vector of strings that contains strings with the other 2 characters
removed. However, in place of the removals, I would like to insert
`.`. For instance:

```
//vector<string> residue2 would have the following elements:
//"..CD", "A..D", "AB..", ".B.D", ".BC.", "A.C."
```

Here is my attempt at doing this for `x = 1`. However, I am not able to
generate the 2nd string or generalize for `x` equals any number.

```
vector<int> orignal; 
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) original.push_back(i);
vector<int> data2;
for(int p1 = 0; p1 < length; p1++){
    auto data1 = original
    data1.erase(data1.begin()+p1);
    for(int p2 = 0; p2 < length; p2++){
        data2 = original;
        if(p2 != p1)
            data2.erase(data2.begin()+p2);
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

**Edit:** What I want to achieve is the following: (refer to my pseudo-code for x=1)
Let's say `original = {1, 2, 3}`. Then in the first iteration of the outer `for-loop`, `data1 = {2,3}` and `data2 = {1,2,3}` then `data2={1,2,.}`. In the 2nd iteration of the outer `for-loop`, `data1 = {1,3}` and `data2 = {1,2,.}` then `data2={.,2,3}`. And then this continues one more time for `data1 = {1,2}`. Now this is when I am only removing one element from original. However, I would like to generalize this so that `data1` will have any `x` removals for x < length. And consequently, `data2` will also have `x` removals, but it will methodically remove elements that have not already been removed in `data1`.

Comment: Is this from leetcode?

Comment: Btw, what's the question?

Comment: @Walter I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not clear. First, it's confusing (you dropped the string in favour of  arrays?) Second, it's not in terms "output wanted given input", but what you want to do in various loops. Why do you want that? Are all the intermediate results needed? I showed in my answer how to achieve the result of the second task (of the original question). It does not need the result of the first task (and cannot be done just from the output of task 1 without the original data). Task 1 can be done in a similar fashion.

Comment: I think (guess), you want to call a routine (`do_stuff(data1, data2)`, now shown) with both `data1` and `data2` being lists of elements of `original`, fashioned from `original` in some way that you failed to explain well. Correct? I guess, if you give an example containing all calls to `do_stuff()` for, say, `n=4`, `x=2`, we may be able to understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to loop over all permutations of a set of `bool` (representing in or out). For example

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> generate(std::string const&str, std::size_t x)
{
  const auto size = str.size();
  std::vector<bool> perm(size);
  for(std::size_t i=0; i!=size; ++i)
    perm[i] = i>=x;
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  do {
    auto copy = str;
    for(std::size_t i=0; i!=size; ++i)
      if(!perm[i]) copy[i]='.';
    result.push_back(std::move(copy));
  } while(std::next_permutation(perm.begin(),perm.end()));
  return result;
}
```

For example for `str="ABCDE"` `x=2` we get

```
{"..CDE",".B.DE",".BC.E",".BCD.","A..DE","A.C.E","A.CD.","AB..E","AB.D.","ABC.."}
```

Comment: this is a very helpful answer! Thank you. However, what I wanted is slightly different. Please let me know if the edit I have made to the OP helps in explaining what I want better.

Comment: Sorry, but this is *exactly* what *you said* you want (for residue2). Perhaps you should put more effort in understanding your own requirements, i.e. what you actually want *before* asking?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your string length is n.
And x<=n.

So make a string with `x` 1's and `n-x` 0's.

```
string your_string="...";
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     ss+=(i<=n-x-1)?"0":"1";


do
{
   string temp="";
   for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
     if(ss[i]=='1')
        temp+=".";
     else
        temp+=your_string[i];
   /*  process temp..*/
}
while(next_permutation(ss.begin(),ss.end())
```

---

Example

```
for n=3 x=2
"ABC"
A..  011
.B.  101
..C  110
```